# How to maket chatbot to capture audio from a google meet?

Tags: chatbot, google-hangouts

I am new to developing chat bots. I am trying to figure out if there is a way for a chat bot in google meet to capture audio (or a transcript of the audio) of the whole meeting.

The only thing that seems to deal with audio to some extent I have been able to find so far is dialogflow but it still doesn't seem to offer what I am looking for:
- https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/how/detect-intent-tts
- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/keep-the-dialog-flowing-create-conversational-chatbots-in-hangouts-chat-with-dialogflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with hangout API. The only requests available for a Hangouts chat bot are the ones mentioned in the documentation of [Hangouts Chat API](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/rest-api):

> spaces.get Returns a space.
>
> spaces.list Lists spaces the bot belongs to.
>
> spaces.members.get Returns a member.
>
> spaces.members.list Lists humans (not bots) that belong to the space.
>
> spaces.messages.create Creates a message.
>
> spaces.messages.delete Deletes a message.
>
> spaces.messages.get Returns a message.
>
> spaces.messages.update Updates a message.

Comment: Since now other replies, I am accepting this as the correct answer.